# iOS POST HTTPS request with wide card certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, https, nsurlconnection

I am purchasing a comodo ssl certificate to enable HTTPS REST service.

Maybe this is a dump question, but I just need to make sure I don't buy the wrong certificate:

Do the widecard SSL certificates work for my purpose on iOS client, or do I need to get a non-widecard SSL certificate specifically for the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate is not for the url but for the domain :
- A normal (not wildcard ) certificate for example.com is valid for https://example.com/* (* means anything)
- A Wildcard certificate for *.example.com is valid for https://*.example.com/*
- A certificate may be valid for more than one domain : example.com + www.example.com + example.us  for example.

Warning : a wildcard certificate is valid only for ONE LEVEL : *.example.com is valid for https://a.example.com/* but NOT for https://b.a.example.com/*

So, for a REST service, a wildcard can work, but it's not the only solution.

Comment: @sean If that answer your question, you can validate it with the check mark :)

Comment: I'll. Just want to see if someone has tried wildcard cert with iOS SDK successfully or not.  I totally agree with your explanation, but still worry iOS SDK would act things differently. I am a paranoid person :-)